# Minecraft Error Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, error, java

Minecraft hasn't been working for a while now. I've just been getting the same response over and over. Mods or any other version of Minecraft won't work. I've tried deleting and downloading Minecraft, deleting and downloading Minecraft, etc. Any idea on how to fix? (If you need more information on it I might be able to try to send it.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't look like an Apple hardware or software question but more of a Minecraft question. It would probably be a better fit on [Arqade.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: That looks like build 74 of Java 8 which is very old, the current Java 8 build is 333